# Python 3.7: Initialize objects with dataclasses module?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Here is the my code in python 3.6

```
class A(object)

    def __init__(self, a: str):
        self._int_a: int = int(a)  # desired composition

    def get_int_a(self) -> int:
        return self._int_a
```

I want to rewrite this code in `python 3.7`, how can i initialize `self._int_a: int = int(a)` with `dataclasses` module?

I know that i can do something like that but i can't get how to initialize `_a: int = int(a)` or similar to that.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class A(object):
    _a: int = int(a)  # i want to get initialized `int` object here

def get_int_a(self) -> int:
    return self._a
```

Thanks in advance for your ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do away with getters and setters entirely and just use attribute access.  We can define an [init only field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables) that accepts a string and then convert that string to an integer field in our [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) call.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field

@dataclass
class A:
    temp: InitVar[str]
    a: int = field(init=False)
    def __post_init__(self, temp):
        self.a = int(temp)

x = A("1")
print(type(x.a), x.a)
# <class 'int'> 1
```

Comment: What I can't understand with the mechanism is that in the end, `temp` remains as a field for the final object... The dataclass mechanism should remove it completely from the fields (as is done when called the module-level `fields` method, but not done in `__dataclass_fields__`).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  `x.temp` should lead to an AttributeError

Comment: Indeed, I was confused, it leads to an AttributeError as expected.

Comment: OK, now I see what was the issue: imagine the same example but now give a default value to temp in the class definition. Now you don't have an AttributeError, which is weird.

Comment: ok but this breaks keyword init

Comment: @JulesG.M. not sure what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: `A(a=1234)` won't work, right? because a isn't in the `__init__` method, `temp` is. So if you're initializing from a `**dict`, your out of luck

Comment: was trying to get something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376099/python-dataclass-from-a-nested-dict