# Python dataclass from a nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

The standard library in 3.7 can recursively convert a dataclass into a dict (example from the docs):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Point:
     x: int
     y: int

@dataclass
class C:
     mylist: List[Point]

p = Point(10, 20)
assert asdict(p) == {'x': 10, 'y': 20}

c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])
tmp = {'mylist': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}
assert asdict(c) == tmp
```

I am looking for a way to turn a dict back into a dataclass when there is nesting. Something like `C(**tmp)` only works if the fields of the data class are simple types and not themselves dataclasses. I am familiar with [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/), which however comes with a prominent security warning.

---

EDIT:

Answers have suggested the following libraries:

- dacite
- mashumaro (I used for a while, works well but I quickly ran into tricky corner cases)
- pydantic (works very well, excellent documentation and fewer corner cases)

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of is indeed asking the same, but the answer given there does not work for this particular example. I've left a comment there and still looking for a more general answer.

Comment: Could you make that difference explicit here?  It looks like you may have to add an `elif` to that `if` that checks for various hints.  I'm not sure how you would generalize it to arbitrary type hints though (`Dict` and `Tuple` in addition to `List`, for example)

Comment: `asdict` is losing information. It would not be possible to do this in the general case.

Comment: Specifically, `asdict` doesn't store any information about what class the dict was produced from. Given `class A: x: int` and `class B: x: int`, should `{'x': 5}` be used to create an instance of `A` or `B`? You seem to be making the assumption that the list of attribute names uniquely defines a list, and that there is an existing mapping of names to data classes that could be used to select the correct class.

Comment: I would recommend you to check out this [library](https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite#dacite).

Comment: what is wrong with `Constructor(**dic)`?

Comment: @CharlieParker if you change var name or remove var from dataclass, dict from old version will generate exception during instantiation.

Comment: dataclasses should be a keyword in python: [dataclass as a keyword](https://youtube.com/live/0lCIkY32AdI?feature=share)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Below is the CPython implementation of `asdict`
– or specifically, the internal recursive helper function `_asdict_inner` that it uses:

```
# Source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/dataclasses.py

def _asdict_inner(obj, dict_factory):
    if _is_dataclass_instance(obj):
        result = []
        for f in fields(obj):
            value = _asdict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name), dict_factory)
            result.append((f.name, value))
        return dict_factory(result)
    elif isinstance(obj, tuple) and hasattr(obj, '_fields'):
        # [large block of author comments]
        return type(obj)(*[_asdict_inner(v, dict_factory) for v in obj])
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        # [ditto]
        return type(obj)(_asdict_inner(v, dict_factory) for v in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return type(obj)((_asdict_inner(k, dict_factory),
                          _asdict_inner(v, dict_factory))
                         for k, v in obj.items())
    else:
        return copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

`asdict` simply calls the above with some assertions, and `dict_factory=dict` by default.

> How can this be adapted to create an output dictionary with the required type-tagging, as mentioned in the comments?

---

**1. Adding type information**

My attempt involved creating a custom return wrapper inheriting from `dict`:

```
class TypeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, t, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TypeDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not isinstance(t, type):
            raise TypeError("t must be a type")

        self._type = t

    @property
    def type(self):
        return self._type
```

Looking at the original code, only the first clause needs to be modified to use this wrapper, as the other clauses only handle *containers* of `dataclass`-es:

```
# only use dict for now; easy to add back later
def _todict_inner(obj):
    if is_dataclass_instance(obj):
        result = []
        for f in fields(obj):
            value = _todict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name))
            result.append((f.name, value))
        return TypeDict(type(obj), result)

    elif isinstance(obj, tuple) and hasattr(obj, '_fields'):
        return type(obj)(*[_todict_inner(v) for v in obj])
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return type(obj)(_todict_inner(v) for v in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return type(obj)((_todict_inner(k), _todict_inner(v))
                         for k, v in obj.items())
    else:
        return copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

Imports:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields, is_dataclass

# thanks to Patrick Haugh
from typing import *

# deepcopy 
import copy
```

Functions used:

```
# copy of the internal function _is_dataclass_instance
def is_dataclass_instance(obj):
    return is_dataclass(obj) and not is_dataclass(obj.type)

# the adapted version of asdict
def todict(obj):
    if not is_dataclass_instance(obj):
         raise TypeError("todict() should be called on dataclass instances")
    return _todict_inner(obj)
```

Tests with the example dataclasses:

```
c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])

print(c)
cd = todict(c)

print(cd)
# {'mylist': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}

print(cd.type)
# <class '__main__.C'>
```

Results are as expected.

---

**2. Converting back to a `dataclass`**

The recursive routine used by `asdict` can be re-used for the reverse process, with some relatively minor changes:

```
def _fromdict_inner(obj):
    # reconstruct the dataclass using the type tag
    if is_dataclass_dict(obj):
        result = {}
        for name, data in obj.items():
            result[name] = _fromdict_inner(data)
        return obj.type(**result)

    # exactly the same as before (without the tuple clause)
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return type(obj)(_fromdict_inner(v) for v in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return type(obj)((_fromdict_inner(k), _fromdict_inner(v))
                         for k, v in obj.items())
    else:
        return copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

Functions used:

```
def is_dataclass_dict(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, TypeDict)

def fromdict(obj):
    if not is_dataclass_dict(obj):
        raise TypeError("fromdict() should be called on TypeDict instances")
    return _fromdict_inner(obj)
```

Test:

```
c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])
cd = todict(c)
cf = fromdict(cd)

print(c)
# C(mylist=[Point(x=0, y=0), Point(x=10, y=4)])

print(cf)
# C(mylist=[Point(x=0, y=0), Point(x=10, y=4)])
```

Again as expected.

Comment: TL;DR, +1 for the comprehensiveness for the answer.

Comment: +0: +1 for trying it, but -1 because it's basically a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: @wim I'd agree tbh - can't see it as much more than a theoretical exercise (which at least shows that `dataclass` plays well with existing object types).

Comment: I'm going to accept this as it's the most comprehensive answer that helps future users understand the core of the issue. I ended up with something closer to @Martijn's suggestion as I did indeed want JSON. Thank you everyone for your answers

Answer (score 169):

I'm the author of [`dacite`](https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite) - the tool that simplifies creation of data classes from dictionaries.

This library has only one function `from_dict` - this is a quick example of usage:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict

@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    age: int
    is_active: bool

data = {
    'name': 'john',
    'age': 30,
    'is_active': True,
}

user = from_dict(data_class=User, data=data)

assert user == User(name='john', age=30, is_active=True)
```

Moreover `dacite` supports following features:

- nested structures
- (basic) types checking
- optional fields (i.e. typing.Optional)
- unions
- collections
- values casting and transformation
- remapping of fields names

... and it's well tested - 100% code coverage!

To install dacite, simply use pip (or pipenv):

```
$ pip install dacite
```

Comment: awesome! How can we propose to add this functionality to the python standard library? :-)

Comment: I can't understand why the heck Python bring Dataclasses but not added possibility to create them from dictionary including nested classes.

Comment: It's also pretty slow, unfortunately. though the validation is quite a nice feature.

Comment: @rv.kvetch - you can try this branch https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite/tree/feature/performance-improvements it has multiple performance improvements

Comment: @KonradHałas I was able to test it out, and looks like performance is slightly improved, though it still appears to be [about the same](https://gist.github.com/rnag/39607185397dc094d4dd8a464af7bce0).

Comment: As of today, I get the opposite results to the claim that pedantic dataclasses are faster than dacite (above comments and the link to their benchmark). Ran the code linked for benchmark as is and dacite is about 200 ms quicker at 0.4 while pendantic was at 0.6

Comment: how did we come to the point where, to fix the problem of the synthetic sugar, we install an additional dependency?

Comment: @Alex,  i was going to suggest the same. Add to the standard library...  although this is in the standard library: `from dataclasses import make_dataclass`.

Comment: the dataclass (and its methods and attributes) should be a keyword in python: [dataclass as keyword](https://youtube.com/live/0lCIkY32AdI?feature=share).

Answer (score 73):

All it takes is a five-liner:

```
def dataclass_from_dict(klass, d):
    try:
        fieldtypes = {f.name:f.type for f in dataclasses.fields(klass)}
        return klass(**{f:dataclass_from_dict(fieldtypes[f],d[f]) for f in d})
    except:
        return d # Not a dataclass field
```

Sample usage:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float

@dataclass
class Line:
    a: Point
    b: Point

line = Line(Point(1,2), Point(3,4))
assert line == dataclass_from_dict(Line, asdict(line))
```

Full code, including to/from json, here at gist: https://gist.github.com/gatopeich/1efd3e1e4269e1e98fae9983bb914f22

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Five lines of code, no external dependencies. +1

Comment: Ok, tested this intensively, and now I know why it is not. This code is buggy. Nevertheless, it is the best concept to this specific question and debugged works really well.

Comment: doesn't work with nested lists of dataclass elements for me :(

Comment: Shouldn't the `except` be catching something specific like a `KeyError`?

Comment: Also breaks for `Optional` fields.

Comment: make sure you add ```import dataclasses``` before running this

Comment: it doesn't handle `List`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Of course there are unsupported cases, I just shared code that is useful for me. **The point is about using `dataclasses.fields()`**

Comment: with `from __future__ import annotations`, any type hint becomes a str type.

Answer (score 47):

Using no additional modules, you can make use of the [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) function to automatically convert the `dict` values to the correct type. This function is called after `__init__`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


@dataclass
class Bar:
    fee: str
    far: str

@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: Bar

    def __post_init__(self):
        if isinstance(self.bar, dict):
            self.bar = Bar(**self.bar)

foo = Foo(bar=Bar(fee="La", far="So"))

d= asdict(foo)
print(d)  # {'bar': {'fee': 'La', 'far': 'So'}}
o = Foo(**d)
print(o)  # Foo(bar=Bar(fee='La', far='So'))
```

This solution has the added benefit of being able to use non-dataclass objects. As long as its `str` function can be converted back, it's fair game. For example, it can be used to keep `str` fields as `IP4Address` internally.

Comment: This is the simplest solution and doesn't rely on custom functions or external libraries so much more portable. It also works well with collections and nesting multiple classes with collections. Should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Good solution! But how do you manage typing properly? If you add `d2 = {'bar': {'fee': 'La', 'far': 'So'}}` and `o2 = Foo(**d2)` you will get `"dict[str, str]" is incompatible with "Bar"` until you change to `Foo` to `bar: Bar|dict`; but if you do, and add `fee = o2.bar.fee`, you will get `Argument of type "dict[str, str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "bar" of type "Bar" in function "__init__" Cannot access member "fee" for type "dict[Unknown, Unknown]" Member "fee" is unknown`

Comment: A solution to the typing issue in my previous comment is not to define `__post_init__` but to define `__init__`:
`def __init__(self, bar:Bar|dict) -> None:`  `if isinstance(bar, dict):`  `self.bar = Bar(**bar)`  `else:`  `self.bar = bar`

Answer (score 16):

You can use [mashumaro](https://github.com/Fatal1ty/mashumaro) for creating dataclass object from a dict according to the scheme. Mixin from this library adds convenient `from_dict` and `to_dict` methods to dataclasses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
from mashumaro import DataClassDictMixin

@dataclass
class Point(DataClassDictMixin):
     x: int
     y: int

@dataclass
class C(DataClassDictMixin):
     mylist: List[Point]

p = Point(10, 20)
tmp = {'x': 10, 'y': 20}
assert p.to_dict() == tmp
assert Point.from_dict(tmp) == p

c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])
tmp = {'mylist': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}
assert c.to_dict() == tmp
assert C.from_dict(tmp) == c
```

Comment: wow, this is great. If the dependencies on msgpack and pyyaml were optional, I could see this being included in the standard library at some point. It's such a no-brainer to add serialization to dataclasses, it's probably one of the most common reasons to use them in the first place.

Comment: @GiorgioBalestrieri Better late than never, but since version 3.0 msgpack and pyyaml are optional.

Answer (score 13):

A possible solution that I haven't seen mentioned yet is to use [`dataclasses-json`](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/). This library provides conversions of `dataclass` instances to/from JSON, but also to/from `dict` (like [`dacite`](https://pypi.org/project/dacite/) and [`mashumaro`](https://pypi.org/project/mashumaro/), which were suggested in earlier answers).

`dataclasses-json` requires decorating the classes with `@dataclass_json` in addition to `@dataclass`. The decorated classes then get a couple of member functions for conversions to/from JSON and to/from `dict`:

- `from_dict(...)`
- `from_json(...)`
- `to_dict(...)`
- `to_json(...)`

Here is a slightly modified version of the original code in the question. I've added the required `@dataclass_json` decorators and `assert`s for the conversion from `dict`s to instances of `Point` and `C`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json
from typing import List

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Point:
     x: int
     y: int

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class C:
     mylist: List[Point]

p = Point(10, 20)

assert asdict(p) == {'x': 10, 'y': 20}
assert p == Point.from_dict({'x': 10, 'y': 20})

c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])

tmp = {'mylist': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}

assert asdict(c) == tmp
assert c == C.from_dict(tmp)
```

Comment: Probably the simplest implementation for those looking for the easiest implementation.

Answer (score 9):

If your goal is to produce *JSON* from and to **existing, predefined** dataclasses, then just write custom encoder and decoder hooks. Do not use `dataclasses.asdict()` here, instead record *in JSON* a (safe) reference to the original dataclass.

`jsonpickle` is not safe because it stores references to *arbitrary* Python objects and passes in data to their constructors. With such references I can get jsonpickle to reference internal Python data structures and create and execute functions, classes and modules at will. But that doesn't mean you can't handle such references unsafely. Just verify that you only import (not call) and then verify that the object is an actual dataclass type, before you use it.

The framework can be made generic enough but still limited only to JSON-serialisable types *plus `dataclass`-based instances*:

```
import dataclasses
import importlib
import sys

def dataclass_object_dump(ob):
    datacls = type(ob)
    if not dataclasses.is_dataclass(datacls):
        raise TypeError(f"Expected dataclass instance, got '{datacls!r}' object")
    mod = sys.modules.get(datacls.__module__)
    if mod is None or not hasattr(mod, datacls.__qualname__):
        raise ValueError(f"Can't resolve '{datacls!r}' reference")
    ref = f"{datacls.__module__}.{datacls.__qualname__}"
    fields = (f.name for f in dataclasses.fields(ob))
    return {**{f: getattr(ob, f) for f in fields}, '__dataclass__': ref}

def dataclass_object_load(d):
    ref = d.pop('__dataclass__', None)
    if ref is None:
        return d
    try:
        modname, hasdot, qualname = ref.rpartition('.')
        module = importlib.import_module(modname)
        datacls = getattr(module, qualname)
        if not dataclasses.is_dataclass(datacls) or not isinstance(datacls, type):
            raise ValueError
        return datacls(**d)
    except (ModuleNotFoundError, ValueError, AttributeError, TypeError):
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid dataclass reference {ref!r}") from None
```

This uses [JSON-RPC-style class hints](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification_v1#a3.JSONClasshinting) to name the dataclass, and on loading this is verified to still be a data class with the same fields. No type checking is done on the values of the fields (as that's a whole different kettle of fish).

Use these as the `default` and `object_hook` arguments to `json.dump[s]()` and `json.load[s]()`:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(c, default=dataclass_object_dump, indent=4))
{
    "mylist": [
        {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "__dataclass__": "__main__.Point"
        },
        {
            "x": 10,
            "y": 4,
            "__dataclass__": "__main__.Point"
        }
    ],
    "__dataclass__": "__main__.C"
}
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(c, default=dataclass_object_dump), object_hook=dataclass_object_load)
C(mylist=[Point(x=0, y=0), Point(x=10, y=4)])
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(c, default=dataclass_object_dump), object_hook=dataclass_object_load) == c
True
```

or create instances of the [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) and [`JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) classes with those same hooks.

Instead of using fully qualifying module and class names, you could also use a separate registry to map permissible type names; check against the registry on encoding, and again on decoding to ensure you don't forget to register dataclasses as you develop.

Answer (score 3):

I know there's probably tons of JSON serialization libraries out there by now actually, and to be honest I might have stumbled upon this article a bit late. However, a newer (and well-tested) option also available is the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. This has recently (as of two weeks ago in any case) moved to the *Production/Stable* status as of the v0.18.0 release.

It has pretty solid support for typing generics from the `typing` module, as well as other niche use cases such as dataclasses in `Union` types and patterned dates and times. Other nice-to-have features that I have personally found quite useful, such as auto *key casing* transforms (i.e. camel to snake) and implicit *type* casts (i.e. string to annotated `int`) are implemented as well.

Ideal usage is with the `JSONWizard` Mixin class, which provides useful class methods such as:

- `from_json`
- `from_dict` / `from_list`
- `to_dict`
- `to_json` / `list_to_json`

Here's a pretty self-explanatory usage that has been tested in *Python 3.7+* with the included `__future__` import:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class C(JSONWizard):
    my_list: list[Point]


@dataclass
class Point(JSONWizard):
    x: int
    y: int


# Serialize Point instance
p = Point(10, 20)
tmp = {'x': 10, 'y': 20}
assert p.to_dict() == tmp
assert Point.from_dict(tmp) == p

c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])
# default case transform is 'camelCase', though this can be overridden
# with a custom Meta config supplied for the main dataclass.
tmp = {'myList': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}
assert c.to_dict() == tmp
assert C.from_dict(tmp) == c
```

---

*NB*: It's worth noting that, technically, you only need to sub-class the main dataclass, i.e. the model being serialized; the nested dataclasses can be left alone if desired.

If a class inheritance model is not desired altogether, the other option is to use exported helper functions such as `fromdict`, `asdict` to convert dataclass instance to/from Python `dict` objects as needed.

Comment: how does your library differ from [dataclasses-json](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/)? the latter seems to be earlier and has more stars.

Comment: I do certainly like `dataclasses-json` which is a similar library that can be used to achieve the same result. I actually added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69133191/10237506) that explains similarities and usage between the two. I believe the main difference is that dataclasses-json relies on external libraries such as `marshmallow` to generate a schema; whereas the dataclass-wizard only requires Python stdlib. As a result, it's slightly faster; if curious, you can check out some benchmarks I added [here](https://github.com/rnag/dataclass-wizard/tree/main/benchmarks).

Comment: An important thing to note is that dataclasses-json supports a few additional features that this library doesn't support currently. For example, converting a dataclass to [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/). However, I do plan to add support for this in a future release, as I agree this can be a common use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my own implementation based on the methods already proposed. I find it cleaner and more robust. Notably, it deals with by-product field values (i.e. `init=False`), `InitVar` fields and `tp.Generic` type hints:

```py
import typing as tp
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields, is_dataclass

ValueT = tp.TypeVar("ValueT")

def dataclass_from_dict(cls: tp.Type[ValueT],
                        src: tp.Mapping[str, tp.Any]) -> ValueT:
    kwargs = {}
    fields_lookup = {field.name: field for field in fields(cls)}
    for field_name, value in src.items():
        try:
            field = fields_lookup[field_name]
            if not field.init:
                continue
        except KeyError:
            annotations = {
                k:v for c in cls.mro()[:-1][::-1]
                for k,v in tp.get_type_hints(c).items()}
            field = annotations[field_name]
            assert isinstance(field, InitVar)
        if tp.get_origin(field) is tp.Union and type(None) in tp.get_args(field):
            field_type = tp.get_args(field.type)[0]
        else:
            field_type = tp.get_origin(field.type) or field.type
        if is_dataclass(field_type) and value is not None:
            kwargs[field_name] = dataclass_from_dict(field_type, value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            _, subfield_type = tp.get_args(field.type)
            kwargs[field_name] = {}
            for key, data in value.items():
                if isinstance(data, dict):
                    kwargs[field_name][key] = dataclass_from_dict(
                        subfield_type, data)
                else:
                    kwargs[field_name][key] = data
        else:
            kwargs[field_name] = value
    return cls(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Now fix it to work with invalid dict (for example if dataclass has new version and loads from dict from old version), load default value or default_factory if value is not correct, and to work with `from __future__ import annotations`  because type hint may be a string in such case, then your answer will be the most correct.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution that supports lists as well (and can be extended for other generic uses)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, fields, is_dataclass
from typing import List
from types import GenericAlias

def asdataclass(klass, d):
    if not is_dataclass(klass):
        return d
    values = {}
    for f in fields(klass):
        if isinstance(f.type, GenericAlias) and f.type.__origin__ == list:
            values[f.name] = [asdataclass(f.type.__args__[0], d2) for d2 in d[f.name]]
        else:
            values[f.name] = asdataclass(f.type,d[f.name])
    return klass(**values)

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

@dataclass
class C:
    mylist: list[Point]
    title: str = ""

c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])

assert c == asdataclass(C, asdict(c))
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769644/871166

Comment: This fails if the class contains a field that does not exist in the dictionary.  It can easily be fixed by checking to make sure the field name exists in the dictionary's keys, and returning None if it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I really think that concept presented by gatopeich in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769644/10743742) answer is the best approach for this question.

I've fixed and civilized his code. This is a correct function to load dataclass back from dictionary:

```
def dataclass_from_dict(cls: type, src: t.Mapping[str, t.Any]) -> t.Any:
    field_types_lookup = {
        field.name: field.type
        for field in dataclasses.fields(cls)
    }

    constructor_inputs = {}
    for field_name, value in src.items():
        try:
            constructor_inputs[field_name] = dataclass_from_dict(field_types_lookup[field_name], value)
        except TypeError as e:
            # type error from fields() call in recursive call
            # indicates that field is not a dataclass, this is how we are
            # breaking the recursion. If not a dataclass - no need for loading
            constructor_inputs[field_name] = value
        except KeyError:
            # similar, field not defined on dataclass, pass as plain field value
            constructor_inputs[field_name] = value

return cls(**constructor_inputs)
```

Then you can test with following:

```
@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float


@dataclass
class Line:
    a: Point
    b: Point

p1, p2 = Point(1,1), Point(2,2)
line = Line(p1, p1)

assert line == dataclass_from_dict(Line, asdict(line))
```

Comment: Worth noting that this doesn't cast optional fields (e.g. `a: Point | None = None`).

Answer (score 1):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, is_dataclass

@dataclass
class test2:
    a: str = 'name'
    b: int = 222

@dataclass
class test:
    a: str = 'name'
    b: int = 222
    t: test2 = None

a = test(a = 2222222222, t=test2(a="ssss"))
print(a)

def dataclass_from_dict(schema: any, data: dict):
    data_updated = {
        key: (
            data[key]
            if not is_dataclass(schema.__annotations__[key])
            else dataclass_from_dict(schema.__annotations__[key], data[key])
        )
        for key in data.keys()
    }
    return schema(**data_updated)

print(dataclass_from_dict(test, {'a': 1111111, 't': {'a': 'nazwa'} }))
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations for your code and structure? Helps put your solution to OP's question into context of the error

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative might be a lightweight chili library:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import List

from chili import init_dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
     x: int
     y: int

@dataclass
class C:
     mylist: List[Point]

p = Point(10, 20)
assert asdict(p) == {'x': 10, 'y': 20}

c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])
tmp = {'mylist': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}
assert asdict(c) == tmp

assert c == init_dataclass(tmp, C)
```

Chili supports almost the entire typing module, including custom Generic types.
You can read more here: https://github.com/kodemore/chili

Installation can be done through pip or poetry by simply running:

`pip install chili`

or

`poetry add chili`

It has only one dependency, which is typing extensions.

Comment: This is fantastic. Under-rated :)

Answer (score 0):

[undictify](https://github.com/Dobiasd/undictify) is a library which could be of help. Here is a minimal usage example:

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, NamedTuple, Optional, Any

from undictify import type_checked_constructor


@type_checked_constructor(skip=True)
@dataclass
class Heart:
    weight_in_kg: float
    pulse_at_rest: int


@type_checked_constructor(skip=True)
@dataclass
class Human:
    id: int
    name: str
    nick: Optional[str]
    heart: Heart
    friend_ids: List[int]


tobias_dict = json.loads('''
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tobias",
        "heart": {
            "weight_in_kg": 0.31,
            "pulse_at_rest": 52
        },
        "friend_ids": [2, 3, 4, 5]
    }''')

tobias = Human(**tobias_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Validobj](https://github.com/Zaharid/validobj) does just that. Compared to  other libraries, it provides a simpler interface (just one function at the moment) and emphasizes informative error messages. For example, given a schema like

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import Optional, List


@dataclasses.dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    phone: Optional[str] = None
    tasks: List[str] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)
```

One gets an error like

```py
>>> import validobj
>>> validobj.parse_input({
...      'phone': '555-1337-000', 'address': 'Somewhereville', 'nme': 'Zahari'}, User
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
WrongKeysError: Cannot process value into 'User' because fields do not match.
The following required keys are missing: {'name'}. The following keys are unknown: {'nme', 'address'}.
Alternatives to invalid value 'nme' include:
  - name

All valid options are:
  - name
  - phone
  - tasks
```

for a typo on a given field.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using the Composite Pattern to solve this,
the main advantage is that you could continue adding classes to this pattern
and have them behave the same way.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class CompositeDict:
    def as_dict(self):
        retval = dict()
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if key in self.__dataclass_fields__.keys():
                if type(value) is list:
                    retval[key] = [item.as_dict() for item in value]
                else:
                    retval[key] = value
        return retval

@dataclass
class Point(CompositeDict):
    x: int
    y: int


@dataclass
class C(CompositeDict):
    mylist: List[Point]


c = C([Point(0, 0), Point(10, 4)])
tmp = {'mylist': [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 10, 'y': 4}]}
assert c.as_dict() == tmp
```

as a side note, you could employ a factory pattern within the CompositeDict class that would handle other cases like nested dicts, tuples and such, which would save much boilerplate.

Comment: This solution is poor, it's too much complicated, you should rather use external library like "dacite".

Comment: @jurass if the OP wanted to use a library he wouldn't ask this question

Answer (score 0):

```
from validated_dc import ValidatedDC
from dataclasses import dataclass

from typing import List, Union


@dataclass
class Foo(ValidatedDC):
    foo: int


@dataclass
class Bar(ValidatedDC):
    bar: Union[Foo, List[Foo]]


foo = {'foo': 1}
instance = Bar(bar=foo)
print(instance.get_errors())  # None
print(instance)               # Bar(bar=Foo(foo=1))

list_foo = [{'foo': 1}, {'foo': 2}]
instance = Bar(bar=list_foo)
print(instance.get_errors())  # None
print(instance)               # Bar(bar=[Foo(foo=1), Foo(foo=2)])
```

validated_dc:
https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

And see a more detailed example:
https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc/blob/master/examples/detailed.py