# how to convert a dict to a dataclass (reverse of asdict)?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

the dataclasses module lets users make a dict from a dataclass reall conveniently, like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    ''' description of the dataclass '''
    a: int
    b: int
    
# create instance
c = MyDataClass(100, 200)
print(c)

# turn into a dict
d = asdict(c)
print(d)
```

But i am trying to do the reverse process: dict -> dataclass.

The best that i can do is unpack a dict back into the predefined dataclass.

```py
# is there a way to convert this dict to a dataclass ?
my_dict = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
e = MyDataClass(**my_dict)
print(e)
```

How can i achieve this without having to pre-define the dataclass (if it is possible) ?

Comment: If you don't pre-define the dataclass, where will the class come from? And what's the point of making it a class?

Comment: Would a [SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) be what you're looking for? Or maybe a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans dataclasses automatically make a constructor when using the syntax OP provided.

Comment: @Barmar, I was thinking that initially, but a similar (reverse) decorator could logically achieve this... ie. a convenient reverse should be possible.

Comment: @Jab,  this seems like a good initial suggestion.

Comment: You may want to also check out the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376099/python-dataclass-from-a-nested-dict) as it is similair to this question. Provides a nice library for dataclass creation from dict as well.

Comment: @Jab, the top answer for that question was great. I see many people have asked for that to be included the standard library...

Comment: @D.L that totally makes sense at least they have provided the `make_dataclass` method though. Techinally speaking AFAIK the way dataclasses work under the hood is they use `eval` on a string that literally has the code to make a class in it. Read here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22349927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`make_dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass):

```py
from dataclasses import make_dataclass

my_dict = {"a": 100, "b": 200}
make_dataclass(
    "MyDynamicallyCreatedDataclass", ((k, type(v)) for k, v in my_dict.items())
)(**my_dict)
```

Comment: brilliant.  i didn't spot this `make_dataclass` method. I always find helpful people here !!!

Comment: Beautiful answer! Not that any changes are needed but just providing another way to do this. You can use zip and map instead of the comprehension: `make_dataclass("MyDynamicallyCreatedDataclass", zip(mydict, map(type, my_dict.values()))`

Comment: two great answers (both of which i didnt expect). I mark this as accepted answer because it is closer to the solution (makes dataclass).

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with unpacking the dict as you showed.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    a: int
    b: int

c = MyDataClass(100, 200)
print(c)
>>> MyDataClass(a=100, b=200)

d = asdict(c)
print(d)
>>> {'a': 100, 'b': 200}

e = MyDataClass(**d)
print(e)
>>> MyDataClass(a=100, b=200)
```

You can't turn a dictionary into a dataclass class that doesn't yet exist. You'll have to create the class before transforming a dict into it. If you really would rather have a class than a dictionary you could use an [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). Otherwise you're just left with shortcut ways to make classes and then turning a dict into those classes.

Comment: that is what i thought (might have been the case) when i was constructing the question, but there are actually 2 great answers that do this...

Comment: Yeah I like those answers, but technically they are merely "shortcut ways to make classes and then turning a dict into those classes" as I said in my answer.

Comment: i was looking for the shortcut :). Logically, all of the info of a dict (keys, values and the types of the values) can be mapped into a dataclass fast. So it makes sense to natively be there...

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) Or a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields). Although this would not be a dataclass it would be it's own object:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
from collections import namedtuple

my_dict = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}

# SimpleNamespace solution
e = SimpleNamespace(**my_dict)

# namedtuple solution
MyClass = namedtuple("MyClass", my_dict)
f = MyClass(**my_dict)
```

---

```
>>> e
namespace(a=100, b=200)
>>> e.a
100
>>> 
>>> MyClass
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> f
MyClass(a=100, b=200)
>>> f.a
100
```

Comment: wow.  2 unexpected excellent answers.  This is cleaner, but the `make_dataclass` solution is also good.  would you have a preference ?

Comment: Well it really depends. SimpleNamespace acts like a dictionary but allows dot notation. It;s essentially an object. You can add, remove, and change keys at any time. But make_dataclass actually constructs a new class type with concrete fields.

Comment: i have upvoted this because of it's elegance (and provides ability to use dot notation)...

Comment: @D.L I also included a solution using `collections.namedtuple` as well just for completeness sake. The namedtuple solution is similair to the dataclass solution where  the class has concrete fields but cannot be modified after creation